# What does the "provisions" and the "article" refer to?

Tags: difference

> Section 5:  The Congress shall have the power to enforce, by appropriate legislation, the **provisions** of this **article**.(from the 14th Amendment)

Does the **article** refer to the whole 14th Amendment? Is one sentence that prescribes something in a section called a provision?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about domain-specific vocabulary, unfamiliar even to most native Anglophones

Comment: @FumbleFingers we answer lots of questions about domain-specific vocabulary: football terminology, for example.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Tens / hundreds of millions of "ordinary people" regularly use / interpret "domain-specific" terminology relating to activities like football - that's ***living*** language which practically changes by the week. The 14th Amendment to the US Constitution, which was written by a bunch of *lawyers* over a century and a half ago *in language which was opaque to the average citizen even then*, isn't remotely comparable.

Answer (score 4):

You might do better to ask this over on Law.SE.But since I post there frequently, I will give the answer I would there.

"*This article*" means the entire amendment. The formal name for the amendments is "articles of amendment", but that term is not as much used as it was 100 years ago.

The "*provisions*" of any law, including an amendment or a whole constitution, are the rules tat the law specifies. One might use "terms" with much the same meaning. A provision may be a paragraph, a sentence, or even a specific clause, depending on how the law is written. For example, the "Equal Protection Clause" of the 14th is a provision. So is the "Free Exercise Clause" of the 1st.

> The Congress shall have the power to enforce, by appropriate legislation, the provisions of this article.

means simply

> Congress is allowed to pass laws to enforce this amendment, or any part of it.